# Wait for firestore query to do some logic for a angular router guard

Tags: angular, firebase, asynchronous, promise, observable

This is my scenario:

I have logged in users (firebase auth).
Each user has a document in `users` collection in firestore.
I want that a user is redirected to page /tutorial if the field `merchantId` is empty in users document.

I have problems with async/overservable/promise logic. `isComplete` on return is undefined.

**registration.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FirestoreService } from '../services/data/firestore.service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegistrationGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private firestoreService: FirestoreService,
    private storage: Storage
  ) { }
  async canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {

    let isComplete;

    let result = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      if (user) {
        let userData = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(`${user.uid}`);

        return userData.get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
              console.log('No such document!');
            } else {
              //console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
              //console.log(doc.data().merchantId)
              let userMerchantId = doc.data().merchantId
              if (userMerchantId.length > 0) {
                isComplete = true
              }
              else {
                isComplete = false
              }
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting document', err);
          });
      }
    });


    if (!isComplete) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/tutorial')
    }

    return isComplete;

  }

 }
```

Comment: what is the result (return type) of firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
// define this way
 let isComplete : boolean; //you can initilise intial value true or false here

// use this way
  this.isComplete  = true;
```

Comment: that does not help. The problem is that only inside userData.get() the needed information for the logic is available. But i don´t know how to where i should place the return that the function canActivate is still without error.